# Sails JS linker: Compiling JADE templates

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, gruntjs, sails.js

Looking into changing my web stack of choice to the awesomeness that is Sails JS, and learning the JADE meta-language. For completeness sake, I thought I'd use JADE for server AND client-side templates.

I added this to my gruntfile:

```
jade: {
  dev: {
    compile: {
      options: {
        client:true
      },
      files: {
        ".tmp/public/jst.js": templateFilesToInject
      }
    }
  }
},
```

and added the task to the `compileAssets` task, however it appears to never run, as I don't have any jst.js file in my .tmp/public folder. How can I check if this is actually being run, or if it's a configuration problem?

The ultimate goal is having the compiled templates in a single file (or multiple in dev.) and have it/them included in the TEMPLATES section in my layout file.

To be clear, this is client-side JADE templates we are talking about.

I am using the `grunt-contrib-jade` plugin.

To summarize:

How can I compile my JADE templates from the /assets/linker/templates folder, and have them included/linked (as compiled .js files) in my layout file?

Comment: Try running `grunt --verbose` and see if that has any helpful output.

Answer (score 0):

So if anyone comes across this at a later date, the issue is that the default order of tasks in sails js is flawed. dev:copy needs to be called before dev:jst. See the compileAssets.js file, this is where the switch needs to be made.